# iOS: This app could not be installed at this time - LegacyErrorString=DuplicateIdentifier

Tags: ios, testing, jenkins, fastlane

I have a project with multiple targets (QA, Staging .. etc). All targets include a dynamic framework (let's say with bundle identifier: com.sdk.demosdk). For some targets, I'm using this SDK compiled with some preprocessor flags (clean) and for others, compiled with different flags.

For example:
for QA - I'm using sdkFull
for QA - I'm using sdkClean

but both have the same bundle identifier.

But anyway, for the test target I always run the target which contains sdkClean.

[image]

I'm using fastlane `scan` to run the tests from Jenkins pipeline. see the code below:

```
lane :testify do |options|
  app = options[:app]
  podinstall
  scan(
      scheme: "DemoTests_" << app,
      code_coverage: true,
      xcargs: "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS='$(inherited) \"-D\" \"COCOAPODS\" -DAUTHENTICATION_PRODUCTION -Dappstore'",
      output_directory: "./fastlane/test_output_" << app,
      device:"iPhone 8"
  )
end
```

And sometimes I get the following error:

> 2018-07-17 02:48:23.975 xcodebuild[82663:24489158] Error
> Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be
> installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app
> could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa8106dab80
> {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=57 "Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework"
> UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=DuplicateIdentifier,
> FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:],
> SourceFileLine=391, NSLocalizedDescription=Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework}}}
> 2018-07-17 02:48:23.975 xcodebuild[82663:24489158] Error
> Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected
> exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be
> attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit,
> operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa8156bf370 {Error
> Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be
> installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app
> could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa8106dab80
> {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=57 "Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework"
> UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=DuplicateIdentifier,
> FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:],
> SourceFileLine=391, NSLocalizedDescription=Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework}}}}}
>
> Testing failed: Test target ShindanTests_DemoApp encountered an error
> (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no
> restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Error
> Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be
> installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app
> could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa8106dab80
> {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=57 "Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework"
> UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=DuplicateIdentifier,
> FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:],
> SourceFileLine=391, NSLocalizedDescription=Found bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdkCleanAPI.framework
> with the same identifier (com.sdk.demosdk) as bundle at
> /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4971F74-AE22-4A18-B5F0-01E71AF71314/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.a0hOWi/extracted/Payload/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/demosdk.framework}}})
> ** TEST FAILED **

I tried several cleanup scripts like:

```
rm -rf -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf $(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache
rm -rf -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.cellebrite.shindan
```

Event killing simulator process and relaunching it, but still, sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not ...

Can anyone help me understand what can be done?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?